# Binding multiple event handler pairs on dynamically generated elements in jquery with on

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I have some dynamically generated elements with the class `my-class` on which I want to bind some events. I have the below code which works properly.

```
$(document).on("event1", ".my-class", function () {
    alert("Event 1");
});

$(document).on("event2", ".my-class", function () {
    alert("Event 2");
});
```

I want to refactor it so that there can be a single call to `on` for the category. Something like this

```
$(document).on(".my-class", {      
    "event1": function() {alert("Event1")},
    "event2": function() {alert("Event2")}
});
```

Is this possible in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way, but I've used this before and it worked for me:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRMc8/)**

I wouldn't delegate off the document, instead I'd use the closest parent container.

JS:

```
$('body').on('click mouseenter', 'div', function(e) {
    if (e.type === 'click') {
        $('div').html('clicked');
    }
    else {   //you'd need an else if here if you had more than two event types
        $('div').html('mouse enter');
    }
});
```